# Notes in a tab application

Tags: xcode, tabs, xcode5

Hy I am trying to make an tab application that in one tab it has a part where you can write notes. and from more that I keep working I don't know how to do that 
and I will be very grateful if you can help me getting the code
(I'm using Xcode 5)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a tutorial rather than a stack overflow answer.

here is one on using a UITextView:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uitextview_uitextviewdelegate_2/

I have also always found Ray Wenderlich tutorials to be great - this one might be a bit advanced however:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial

Good luck!

Comment: Tanks it help me a lot